# Completing a multiplication table with asterisks

Tags: java, for-loop

I would like to make a program (using loops) that would display a table that looks like this:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
---------------------------------------
9:    9   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
8:    8  16   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
7:    7  14  21   *   *   *   *   *   *
6:    6  12  18  24   *   *   *   *   *
5:    5  10  15  20  25   *   *   *   *
4:    4   8  12  16  20  24   *   *   *
3:    3   6   9  12  15  18  21   *   *
2:    2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16   *
1:    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

I could print the whole table completely (that is, without the asterisks) but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to insert the asterisks in a loop.

What I have written so far looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("  |"); 
    for (int a = 1; a < 10; a++){
        int ans = a;
        if (ans < 10) {
            System.out.print("  "+ ans + "  ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" " + ans + "  ");
        } 

    }System.out.println();
    for (int u = 1; u < 47; u++){
        System.out.print("-");
    } 
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 9; i > 0; i --) { 
        System.out.print(i + " |");
            for (int c = 1; c < 10; c++) { 
                int ans2 = i * c;
                if (ans2 < 10) {
                System.out.print("  "+ ans2 + "  ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" " + ans2 + "  ");
                }
            }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
```

I'm still a novice in Java and I would appreciate it if you could help me. Thanks in advance for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is fine.I made a small correction and it worked perfect

added a small logic to change the way you print your output(if(c <= 10-i){ ) and hope you can understand why :)

PFB the source

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("  |"); 
    for (int a = 1; a < 10; a++){
        int ans = a;
        if (ans < 10) {
            System.out.print("  "+ ans + "  ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" " + ans + "  ");
        } 

    }System.out.println();
    for (int u = 1; u < 47; u++){
        System.out.print("-");
    } 
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 9; i > 0; i --) { 
        System.out.print(i + " |");
            for (int c = 1; c < 10; c++) {
                int ans2 = i * c;
                if(c <= 10-i){ //Tweaked the logic here
                if (ans2 < 10) {
                System.out.print("  "+ ans2 + "  ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" " + ans2 + "  ");
                }
                }else {
                    System.out.print(" * ");
                }
            }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you didn't specify where to show '*'s.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("  |");
        for (int a = 1; a < 10; a++){
            int ans = a;
            if (ans < 10) {
                System.out.print("  "+ ans + "  ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" " + ans + "  ");
            }

        }System.out.println();
        for (int u = 1; u < 47; u++){
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 9; i > 0; i --) {
            System.out.print(i + " |");
            for (int c = 1; c < 10; c++) {
                int ans2 = i * c;
                if (c < (11 - i)) {
                    if(ans2 < 10) {
                        System.out.print("  " + ans2 + "  ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" " + ans2 + "  ");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.print("  *  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is that you print an asterisk whenever `c + i >= 11`. If you add a new condition to your innermost `if` statement you can print an asterisk rather than `c * i` when that condition is met.

Just a hint on your code for adding a space for single digit numbers. You might want to take a look at `String.format` for how to do this (in your case the format "%2d" will automatically add the space for you).